# Key size for HMAC-SHA256

Tags: hmac, sha-256

After reading a bunch of past stack exchange posts like [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/what-are-requirements-for-hmac-secret-key) and RFCs [5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869), [2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104#section-3), and [4868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4868#ref-HMAC) I felt comfortable that a 32-byte key was sufficient for HMAC-SHA256.  However, I am implementing my code in C# and someone pointed out to me that the [Microsoft HMAC-SHA256 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9c9tf8wc(v=vs.110).aspx) recommends a 64-byte key:

> The key can be any length. However, the recommended size is 64 bytes.

Is there any good reason to use a 64-byte key instead of a 32-byte key?